# Singapore transit passenger wants to go to Jewel. How?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, singapore

I arrive in T1. I’m in transit and my bags are checked through. During my 7hr layover, can I visit Jewel (the entertainment and retail complex on the inside of Changi Airport) without going through Immigration/Customs? If so, where do I go?